# SqlConnection.ChangeDatabase - How to provide Schema?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a bit confused by SqlConnection's `ChangeDatabase(string databaseName)`.

I thought database names didn't have to be unique if they aren't in the same schema, for example I can have dbo.DatabaseName and hr.DatabaseName .

Every example of `ChangeDatabase` that I have seen though only uses the database Name ... is that just laziness and I can actually provide the full name by using 
`"[dbo].DatabaseName"` as a parameter? Or is there something more to it ?

Comment: Databases don't exist inside a schema.  Schemas exist inside databases.  It's `DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`.  I think you're confusing databases with tables.

Comment: Per Amy, I assume you're just confused about the hierarchy, but you *can* have `dbo.DatabaseName` and `hr.DatabaseName`. In that case, though, the databases would *literally be named* `dbo.DatabaseName` and `hr.DatabaseName`. The period wouldn't mean anything to SQL Server, and there is no subdivision, and trying to access `DatabaseName` would fail. (Also, there is much potential for software to fail if databases are named like that, so please never do it.)

Comment: Database names in one SQL Server must be unique.  dBo is a schema.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server

Comment: Amy is right: there might be Databasename.dbo and Databasename.hr, but NEVER dbo.Databasename and hr.Databasename. However, the full hierarchy would be `ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that cleared it up!

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server, databases are not associated with schemas the way you think.
If you want to see a parent-child relation between them, I would say the database is the parent.

In a database, multiple schemas can exist. Once you create them, you can then define tables and other database objects (even users) that are part of one of the schemas you defined at database-level.

So, the ChangeDatabase method does nothing but executing a "USE {DBNAME}" statement in T-SQL.

Take a look: [USE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)